# MRTK: How to fix SpectatorView from Android-device not pairing with HoloLens? (QR-code)

Tags: qr-code, mrtk

**Problem summary**
I'm attempting to establish a connection between HoloLens and an Android device, which worked sporadically in the beta-version of the MRTK. 
However since moving to the MRTK RC1 (Also Refresh), I've encountered issues regarding the QR-scanning. When pressing connect, the two devices seemingly finds eachother, however when the wearer of the HoloLens1 looks directly into the QR-code, nothing happens. (the white dot and "Locating marker..." text is showing)

**Background summary**
***1. The Setup:***

- Implemented working MRTK RC1 Refresh
- Cloned Feature-SpectatorView separately, copying only the "MixedRealityToolkit.Extensions" folder to the MRTK project.
- "Spectator View - HoloLens" prefab added to scene.
- First pressing "HoloLens" in the PlatformSwitcher, building for HoloLens1, then switching to "Android" and exporting the project to Android Studio.
- Building the .apk from Android Studio

(opencv binaries are downloaded and implemented since beta version, I haven't since changed them from when they worked the last time.)

***2. The Proces:***
On the HoloLens, I press the "Connect" button in which a white text appears  saying "Locating Marker..."

The Android phone presses connect and it goes to "Waiting for User" then as soon as a HoloLens is connected, it switches immediately to a QR code that should be readible from said HoloLens.

Looking directly at the QR-code and nothing new happens, connection does not establish further.

I checked if something was not ticked in Player Settings/Capabilities, but I can't seem to find what the culprit would be.  Did I forget something in this proces?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that could be causing this issue.

If the Android device is showing a marker, this means the two devices have established a network connection and are communicating with one another. Typically, when I run spectator view I enable the following capabilities: "Internet (Client & Server), Internet (Client), Microphone, Pictures Library, Private Networks (Client & Server), Spatial Perception, Videos Library, Webcam" in the Package.appxmanifest in visual studio. Pressing "HoloLens" on spectator view's unity platform switcher should typically achieve enabling these capabilities, but sometimes the package.appxmanifest doesn't get updated correctly in the visual studio project with subsequent builds in Unity. You can fix this by deleting your visual studio directory and rebuilding the visual studio project in unity.

If these capabilities are checked in the package.appxmanifest, it may be that you rejected a capability request when first running the application. If you open Settings -> Privacy -> Camera on the HoloLens, you can check whether your deployed spectator view application has camera access granted. You should be able to enable the camera functionality here if it is disabled.

There have been changes to both MixedRealityToolkit and MixedRealityToolkit-Unity spectator view logic, so cloning these items at different points in time may cause functions to no longer resolve (We're hoping to consolidate this code into the same repo/commit history in the future to prevent this from continuing to happen). Typically, in the Unity logs there will be errors stating that a function was not found for SpectatorViewPlugin.dll if the dll functionality is not resolving correctly. It sounds like this is not the issue you are hitting if things worked previously. But if it does turn out the case, it may be that you need to rebuild the SpectatorViewPlugin.dll to match the feature/spectatorView code you are using.

If you recently copied the SpectatorViewPlugin.dll and its dependencies to a new unity project, it may be that they aren't getting registered as usable by the windows uwp unity player. Make sure these binaries are in a Plugins\WSA\x86 folder within your assets folder. Also check the *.dll.meta definitions in the unity inspector to ensure the dll's are declared as usable for the unity wsa player/x86 builds.